# html link to navigate to section of another page

Tags: html, css

Source page code:

```
<a href="${context_path}/rss-footer-documents#aboutUs">About Us</a>
```

Destination page code:

```
<h3><div id="aboutUs" ">About Us</div></h3>
```

when About Us link is clicked it points to url /rss-footer-documents.html#/termsOfRegistration.

I want it to point to /rss-footer-documents.html#termsOfRegistration.

Since it adds / after # automatically, it simply navigates to the page not to specific section.

Please tell me how to remove / in the url to appear that get added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/n1xtsx42/17/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); /* adding this will remove # which is taken on click of a */

        var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

**Scroll if window url contains #**

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // if window location contains hash
 var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  // getting value after hash
 $target = $('#' + hash);

 $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: The code works like charm, if links are in the same page of sections..but how to make it work if links are to navigate to sections in another page?

Comment: Yeah.. This one will work it seems though haven't tried..thanks a ton for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply add slash on your anchor link like this?

`<a href="${context_path}/rss-footer-documents/#aboutUs">About Us</a>`

Comment: yes.It didn't work.on adding / before # url becomes rss-footer-documents.html/#/termsOfRegistration.

Answer (score 0):

I got a working code.

here, I am triming slash  from window.location.hash and that solves my problem.Please vote if helps you.

```
(function($){

    var jump=function(e)
    {
       if (e){
           e.preventDefault();
           var target = $(this).attr("href");
       }else{
           var target = location.hash.replace('/','');
       }

       $('html,body').animate(
       {
           scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
       },1,function()
       {
           location.hash = target;
       });

    }

    $('html, body').hide()

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

        if (location.hash){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show()
                jump()
            }, 0);
        }else{
          $('html, body').show()
        }
    });

})(jQuery)
```